# HDF5 example not working

Tags: hdf5

I tried building the first example [here](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/Intro/IntroExamples.html#CreateExample) and got errors. Right on the first line there's a missing include statement, but I managed to figure out it should be

```
#include "hdf5.h"
```

But even after fixing that I got more errors:

```
$ h5cc ./example1.c 
./example1.c: In function ‘main’:
./example1.c:66:4: error: too few arguments to function ‘H5Dcreate2’
In file included from /usr/include/hdf5.h:27:0,
                 from ./example1.c:6:
/usr/include/H5Dpublic.h:104:14: note: declared here
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Please show your code, and tag with @LeventeKurusa when you are done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example code was written for release `1.6` of `hdf5`, and as such will simply not compile on a `1.8` release without modification.

If you want to get the code to work on `1.8`, you need to enable `1.6` compatibility, which means passing in the flag:

```
-DH5_USE_16_API
```

to the h5cc command line like:

```
h5cc -DH5_USE_16_API ./example1.c
```

and it should compile correctly; otherwise you will have to rewrite the code to make use of the `1.8` API.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the flag `-DH5Dcreate_vers=1`  (might make sense if you have a mixture of old and new hdf5-functions).